# Running script code (adding a registry key) instead of executable in Run entry in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to add a registry key after the user accept the key addition.
The key will tell Firefox where to find our plugin (which is stored in the app folder)

The user will get a checkbox *"install ff plug-in?"* in the same form as where we ask *"install chrome plugin"* and *"install ie plugin?"*.

```pascal
[Code]
function GetHKLM: Integer;
begin
  if IsWin64 then
    Result := HKLM64
  else
    Result := HKLM32;
end;

function CheckForMozilla: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if RegKeyExists(GetHKLM(), 'SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox') then
  begin
    Result := True;
  end;

  if RegKeyExists(GetHKLM(), 'SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Firefox') then
  begin
    Result := True;
  end;
end;

function AddFFKey : Boolean;
begin
  // Some way to write this key in code section:
  GetHKLM() + '\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\extensions\5e12c5a...'
end;
```

```
[Run]
Filename: AddFFKey; Flags: runascurrentuser postinstall ; \
    Check: CheckForMozilla; Description: "Install firefox plug-in"
```

Thank you all!
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the *Finish* button click by implementing [`NextButtonClick` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NextButtonClick) and replace the executable call with a script procedure call.

```pascal
#define InstallFFPluginDesc "Install firefox plug-in"

[Run]
FileName: "fake.exe"; Flags: postinstall; \
    Description: "{#InstallFFPluginDesc}"; Check: CheckForMozilla

[Code]

procedure AddFFKey;
begin
  Log('Adding FF key');
  RegWriteStringValue(
    GetHKLM(), 'SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\extensions\5e12c5a...', ...);
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    // When restart is needed, the RunList is never populated/shown.
    if WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count > 0 then
    begin
      // Find the RunList entry for the FF plugin
      Index := WizardForm.RunList.Items.IndexOf('{#InstallFFPluginDesc}');
      // Does it exist and is it checked?
      if (Index >= 0) and WizardForm.RunList.Checked[Index] then
      begin
        // Uncheck, so that the fake.exe is not run
        WizardForm.RunList.Checked[Index] := False;
        // Do our scripted action instead
        AddFFKey;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

---

Another alternative is to add a working but noop `[Run]` entry, and use [`BeforeInstall` or `AfterInstall` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall) to call your script code.

It's easier and more robust solution, just with a side-effect (you have to run some process, even though it does not need to do anything).

```pascal
[Run]
FileName: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C echo noop"; Flags: postinstall runhidden; \
    Description: "Install firefox plug-in"; Check: CheckForMozilla; \
    BeforeInstall: AddFFKey

[Code]

procedure AddFFKey;
begin
  Log('Adding FF key');
  ...
end;
```

---

I believe that your `GetHKLM` logic is wrong. The Firefox always writes to 32-bit registry.