# Modify Inno Setup Run section flags according to selected installation type

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a `Run` section:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\myapp.exe"; Description: {cm:RunNow}; \
    Flags: postinstall nowait runascurrentuser;  Check: TypeIsCompact;
Filename: "{app}\myapp.exe"; Description: {cm:RunNow}; \
    Flags: postinstall nowait runasoriginaluser; Check: not TypeIsCompact;
```

And the check `TypeIsCompact`:

```pascal
function TypeIsCompact: Boolean;
begin  
  if SILENT then
    begin
      Result := DONTINSTALLMSSQL;
    end
  else
    begin
      Result := WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex = 1;
    end;
  log('Type is compact: ' + BoolToStr(Result));
end;
```

The check called in the `Run` section returns `True` despite type was not selected yet. With this I'm not able to use the Filename with flag `runasoriginaluser` and myapp.exe is starting with the flag `runascurrentuser`.

I need to run myapp.exe with or without administrator privileges depending on the chosen type.

Is there any direct way or do I have to write custom checkbox for the finish page?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to create your own check box. But I believe you need to implement the execution of the program on your own.

For some example how to re-implement handling of the checkboxes on the "finished" page, see:
[Running script code (adding a registry key) instead of executable in Run entry in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34007625/850848)

In your implementation, use [`Exec`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) or [`ExecAsOriginalUser`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_execasoriginaluser), depending on the installation type selected.