# Inno Setup: How to read the value of checkbox in postinstall

Tags: inno-setup

I have added a checkbox in postinstall:

```
[Run]
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Description: "This is checkbox"; Flags: postinstall shellexec runasoriginaluser unchecked
```

[image]

I want to trigger a function when clicking the button Finish if the checkbox is checked. How can I check the value?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/34007625/850848

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I actually needed to do was the following:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{code:MyFunction}"; Description: "This is a checkbox"; Flags: skipifdoesntexist postinstall skipifsilent

[Code]
function MyFunction(Param: String): String;
var
    ResultCode: Integer;
begin
    //My code
    Result := '';
end;
```

This will trigger MyFunction after pressing Finish only if checkbox is checked. The flag skipifdoesntexist is important here. It prevents error when the required exe file doesn't exist.